Why does one side of my double kitchen sink drain slowly?
I just purchased a house, and the right-side kitchen sink drains very slowly. The left-side sink drains normally, so I believe that the trap and everything beyond it is fine. Looking under the sink, I see this:

I have minimal experience with plumbing, but I do know that connections and angles are important for proper drainage. Is it normal for the right sink to connect below the drain output of the disposal? Could this be the cause of the slow drainage? Or should I pull the elbow from the right side and snake the horizontal line?

It looks fine to me. Have you disassembled the right-hand drain path to check for clogs? You can loosen the plastic nuts and take it all apart with no risk (you don't use a snake for something like this). Maybe there's something wedged in the elbow or tee that only affects flow from that direction.

I would place a level on the horizontal pipe to check for proper slope.  Can't trust the picture.  But probably as in the first comment, a cleaning is all it needs.

It seems to have a slight tilt, but my level is a bit too long to fit well on the pipe. Unless there's something obviously wrong with how the plumbing is set up, it's likely just a matter of cleaning it out.

My money is on the tee fitting. There's a baffle inside. Its role is to prevent flow from one sink basin pushing up into the other basin -- especially flow that is power-driven by the disposer.
The straight-through path in the tee, by virtue of flowing straight and also having the disposer helping to blow it clean, is likely to be fine. The path that branches to the right is likely to have some sludgy waste built up in the bend.
Your tee with its long branch tube is a design I haven't seen before. It won't be easy to clean. I suggest you buy a new "end outlet tee" and an extension tube to replace the single part that's there now. This will be easier to service in the future -- and it'll spare you the unappealing task of cleaning the tee that's there now! ;-) (photo credit: menards.com)



Hm, I do like the idea of avoiding a cleanout...

Why would that long tee be any harder to clean, at least with a long tool?  Everone has a long-handled spoon, no?  All of these connections are just compression nuts, so they're easy to remove.

@Huesmann I'd want to clean the baffle on the branch side of the tee by pushing something through on an angle. A heavy wire, bent on the end, could accomplish that. A straight object like a spoon would let me pack whatever-it-is into the baffle area, but might or might not easily clear it.
